# Celery cannot import Schedules

Tags: python, django, celery

Trying to get celery working with periodic tasks, magically got it working yesterday but after restarting my VM I got a really strange behavior.

My celery beat cannot import schedules anymore from celery

```
from celery impor schedules
```

Bear with me, I didn't write this code and I understand what I does and what the error means. Tough,
when I tried to do the same on bpython I was able to properly import it.

This error occured after installing a packet called django-online-status () Don't know if these two things are really related I just wanted to give you as much info as possible.

Where could that come from ? Any idea on how I should try to fix this issue ? I'd be happy with non-coding tricky methods that you can have.

I'm using Django 1.7 with python 3.2 on a Debian 6 machine

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Place this in your celery config

Comment: Already in there, I figured out I was using Django-Celery with 1.7 version of Django which doesn't need django-celery anymore https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery

Answer (score 0):

I was using Django Celery with 1.7 version of Django which doesn't require Django-Celery anymore. Source at : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery